# Get data from local DB not working

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have create MVC5 application and I have local DB ,currently I have entered data 
to the table and I able to see that in the MDF file under server explorer ->data connections ,now I want to read it via API below and its not working i've provided the ID which I have in the table and I get null ,I think maybe that I need to provide the **connection string** to the API but not sure how ,any idea how to do that?

**This is DB context from the model definition**

```
  public class PersonModelDbContext : DbContext
    {
public PersonModelDbContext()
            : base("Connection1")
        {

        }
```

**This is the read API**

```
private PersonModelDbContext db = new PersonModelDbContext();

public Person GetPrviderData(string id)
{
    Person person = db.Person.Find(id);
    return person;
}
```

**This is the connection string in the WEB CONFIG FILE**

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Connection1" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Person.mdf;Initial Catalog=Persons;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Update - in addition I try with the following without success ,I got error:

```
db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Person.mdf;Initial Catalog=Persons;Integrated Security=True";
```

> An exception of type 'System.Data.DataException' occurred in
>   EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: An exception occurred while initializing the
>   database. See the InnerException for details.

Comment: What is the error? Maybe You miss something

Comment: @lnanikian-there is no error just null when I call to find(id)

Comment: Could you show please your model `Person` code and the action where you call the method `GetPrviderData`?

Comment: You need to look at the inner exception. Use Visual studio to debug and see what it is.

Comment: Did you add the tables to `PersonModelDbContext`? Like: `public Table<Person> Persons;`?

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg-sure (also verify the steps with AVD answer..),I think the problem is that I calling to this db from other project under the solution,maybe i need to change someting?

Comment: Can you show us the (mentioned) InnerException as well?

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting your connection string to more this format since it is local

```xml
 <add name="DataBaseConnectionName" 
      connectionString="Data Source=[ServerNameHere];User ID=[DatabaseLogonID/Probably sa];Password=[DatabasePassword];Initial Catalog=TheNameoftheLocalDB;" 
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

You could try that to establish a connection also don't keep the `[brackets]` in the connection string.